# Check Class attribute against a literal string in BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html

I am scraping some HTML which is structured like this:

```
<span class="ThreadPrime"><a href="url1">Post title 1</a></span>
<span class="ThreadInfo"><a href="url2">Reply title 2</a></span>
```

Given a loop over all the  tags in the document, I want to branch conditionally if the  tag's parent has a certain CSS class, ThreadPrime in this case.

Here's the check I'm trying to use (thisATag is the current iterator in a find_all loop).

```
if thisATag.parent.get("class")=="ThreadPrime"
```

However, this condition never seems to evaluate to true. If I print thisATag.parent.get("class") to the python console, I get

```
[u'ThreadPrime']
[u'ThreadInfo']
```

I'm not sure exactly what to compare against in my conditional. I tried "[u'ThreadPrime']", and 'ThreadPrime', and none of them seemed to match.

Comment: What if you try `"threadprime" in hisatag.parent.class("class")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing a unicode string with a decoded string. See [this](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html) on section Unicode type. Try this:

```
my_string = (thisATag.parent.get("class")).decode('utf-8')
if my_string=="ThreadPrime"
```

Comment: This was it! It also needed an index, because the class attribute is a list (maybe special among the attributes?). So, thisATag.parent.get("class")[0].decode('utf-8').